# Summing columns from multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, sum

I have multiple dataframes that I created in a for loop. They all have the same 3 columns, XLocs, YLocs, PatchStatus. XLocs and YLocs contain the same coordinates in each dataframe. PatchStatus can be either 0 or 1 depending how the model ran. Example of dataframe 1 looks like

```
print(listofdfs[1])

allPoints.xLocs allPoints.yLocs allPoints.patchStatus
1        73.5289654       8.8633913                     0
2        21.0795393      44.4840248                     0
3        51.5969348      21.7864016                     0
4        61.9007129      32.4763183                     1
5        62.3447741      41.0651838                     1
6        16.9311605       6.3765206                     0
```

And dataframe 2 looks like

```
print(listofdfs[2])

 allPoints.xLocs allPoints.yLocs allPoints.patchStatus
1        73.5289654       8.8633913                     0
2        21.0795393      44.4840248                     1
3        51.5969348      21.7864016                     0
4        61.9007129      32.4763183                     1
5        62.3447741      41.0651838                     1
6        16.9311605       6.3765206                     0
```

I'm hoping to have 1 resultant dataframe that has XLocs, YLocs, and SUM of patch status (note I plan on combining 15 data frames, so PatchStatus can be between 0 and 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this answer along with the heatmap - Plot-3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60974584/1691723

```
library('data.table')
df2 <- rbindlist(l = listofdfs)
df2 <- df2[, .(sum_patch = sum(allPoints.patchStatus)), by = .(allPoints.xLocs, allPoints.yLocs)]
```

Comment: check the class using this: `class(data)`. I don't understand where item-1 comes from...

Comment: if you want check classes of all dataframes in a list, you can do `lapply(listofdfs, class)`

Comment: you know function is not a dataframe. Make sure it is dataframe.

Comment: Oh yes, I've seem to have made a  silly mistake. I'm not sure how that happened. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210761/discussion-between-a75awh-and-sathish).

Answer (score 1):

We can bind the datasets together and do a group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(listofdfs) %>%
      group_by( allPoints.xLocs, allPoints.yLocs) %>%
      summarise(allPoints.patchStatus = sum(allPoints.patchStatus))
```

---

Or using `rbind` and `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(allPoints.patchStatus ~ ., do.call(rbind, listofdfs), FUN = sum)
```